# how to pass data in get request for php api hit?

Tags: php, json, postman

I am passing data in body section in the postman with "GET" request with this URL:
"http://localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-json/gh/v3/contacts".
the raw data in body that I am passing is:

```
 {
 "query": {
    "tags_include" : "92"
 }
}
```

this will return all the students that include the tag id "92" without this raw body data the link "http://localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-json/gh/v3/contacts" will return all the students present in the database. 
now my query is I am trying to pass this body section in my code something like that:

```
$tag_args = array(
        "query" => array(
        "tags_include"=>$tag_id
        )
    );
$all_tag_students = $gr->get_tag_contact($tag_args);
```

and get_tag_contact is the function which hits the URL "http://localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-json/gh/v3/contacts" with the body

```
 {
 "query": {
 "tags_include" : "92"
 }
}
```

here is the function that i have created for this to work:

```
  function get_tag_contact($tag_args){
    $emails = array();
    $args = $this->args;
    $args['method'] = 'GET';
    $args['body'] = json_encode($tag_args);
    $response = wp_remote_get($this->apiurl.'contacts',$args);
    $body = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response ) );
    if(!empty($body)){
        foreach ($body->contacts as $contact) 
        {
            $emails[] = $contact->data->email;
        }
        return $emails;
    }
}
```

but the problem here is it returns all the students not only the specific student which contain the ID

```
 Array
(
   [query] => Array
    (
        [tags_include] => 92
    )

)
```

how can I find the student that contains the id "92" only what I am missing here?

Comment: GET requests don't support passing data in the body. If you want to pass data on a GET request, use a query string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the mistake here:

```
function get_tag_contact($tag_args){
    $emails = array();
    $args = $this->args;
    $args['method'] = 'GET';
    $args['body'] = $tag_args;
    $response = wp_remote_get($this->apiurl.'contacts',$args);
    $body = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response ) );
    if(!empty($body)){
        foreach ($body->contacts as $contact) 
        {
            $emails[] = $contact->data->email;
        }
        return $emails;
    }
}
```

i am encoding the the $tag_args.

```
$args['body'] = $tag_args;
```

i just need to remove json_encode from this line and it works perfectly.